# Independence of random vectors

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(X_1,X_2)$ be a random vector verifying $E[f(X_1,X_2)] \leq E[f(Y_1,Y_2)]$ for every real function $f \in C^2(\mathbf{R}^2)$ satisfying $\partial^2 f/\partial x \partial y \geq 0$ and some independent r.v.'s $Y_1, Y_2$ such that $Y_j \overset{\text{d}}{=} X_j$ for each $j=1,2$. It is possible to find nonnegative independent r.v.'s $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ such that the vectors $(Z_1,Z_2)$, $(X_1,X_2)$ are independent and $(Z_1,Z_2)$, $(Y_1,Y_2)$ are dependent? With thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  If you let $(Y_1, Y_2)$ be any random vector, then we can choose $(X_1,X_2)$ so that no such $(Z_1,Z_2)$ exists, or choose $(X_1,X_2)$ so that such a vector does exist.  For instance, if you let $X_1 = Y_1$ and $X_2 = Y_2$ then no such vector can possibly exist.  However, if you let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent copies of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ and set $Z_j = |Y_j|$ then clearly $(X_1,X_2)$ is independent of $(Z_1,Z_2)$ but $(Y_1,Y_2)$ is not independent of $(Z_1,Z_2)$.